# Meteor deployed to aws servers hot code push restart fails

Tags: meteor

I have some Meteor apps running on AWS EC2 instances.

Everything is working fine except when I bundle and then tar -zxvf bundle.tgz into the /bundle directory.

The application does not hot deploy like it does on meteor.com.  I have to reboot the servers.

Here is my service script

> start on runlevel [2345]
>
> stop on runlevel [-2345]
>
> respawn
>
> respawn limit 10 5
>
> script
>   APP_DIR=/home/ubuntu/bundle
>   LOG_FILE=/var/log/app.log
>
> export PORT=80   export
>
> MONGO_URL=mongodb://somelogin:fakepasssword@somedomain:1231231/app_db
>
> export ROOT_URL=http://somedomain.com
>
> /usr/bin/node "$APP_DIR/main.js" 2>&1 >> $LOG_FILE
>
> end script

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deployed apps (made via `meteor bundle`) don't do hot code changes. You have to update the files then stop and restart the node process.

You could use something like forever to keep them running then do a `forever restart` to get them running the new code

To use forever you could have a script with something like:

```
APP_DIR=/home/ubuntu/bundle
export PORT=80
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://somelogin:fakepasssword@somedomain:1231231/app_db
export ROOT_URL=http://somedomain.com
forever start "$APP_DIR/main.js"
```

Then when you update your files in `/home/ubuntu/bundle` just do the same thing above but with `forever restart` instead of `forever start`.

Comment: Also, how would I modify to support forever? And do you mean forever restart would be something command line?

Comment: Hot code pushes basically aren't meant to work in deployed instances (including meteor.com). When you do a meteor deploy it does something like replacing the files and restarting the node process behind the scenes. Using forever is easy ill update the answer with what I use

Comment: when you state "just do the same thing above but with forever restart" do you mean the script should have forever restart in it?  instead of forever start?

Comment: When I restart my node process on EC2, all connected clients get a hot code push. Perhaps your experience is different?

Comment: This is what is supposed to happen. What I mean is if you edit files without restarting your node process (as when developing locally) clients won't get a hot code push on deployed instances

Comment: Do I have to restart the node process or can I just use forever restart in the script and it will notice file changes?

Comment: You can use forever restart, it will restart the node processes, and then make the client's browser refresh, and also keep them running so you could even close the terminal window/ssh session

Answer (score 0):

Have a look inside https://github.com/matb33/meteor-ec2-install for some insight.

Whenever I deploy and node restarts, all connected clients get a hot code push. I'm doing a proper deploy too... Perhaps parts of the hot code push functionality don't carry over such as Sessions, I'm not sure.